# Simplify jQuery validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I wrote a script for validate the input field for following requirements

1. Not null
2. Multiple of hundreds
3. Less than needed amount

Here is my script:

```
    $('#investAmount,#invest-button').bind('keypress', function(event){         
        if(event.which == 13){
            if(amountValidation('#investAmount','#inNeedAmt','#invalidAmt','#mult100','#needAmtValidation')){
                return false;
            }
            else{$(elementId).removeClass('errorField');}
        }
    });
    $('#invest-button').click( function(event){
        if(amountValidation('#investAmount','#inNeedAmt','#invalidAmt','#mult100','#needAmtValidation')){
            return false;
        }
        else{$(elementId).removeClass('errorField');}
    });



function amountValidation(elementId,needAmt,errorMsgId,errorMsgId2,errorMsgId3){    
    var gvAmount =$(elementId).val();

    var errAmount = gvAmount == '';
    if(errAmount == true){$(elementId).addClass('errorField');}
    $(errorMsgId).toggle(errAmount);

    var errGVAmount = !errAmount && !gvAmount.match(/^[1-9]\d*00$/);
    $(errorMsgId2).toggle(errGVAmount); 
    if(errGVAmount == true){$(elementId).addClass('errorField');}

    var errNeedAmount =parseInt($(needAmt).val()) <  parseInt(gvAmount);
    $(errorMsgId3).toggle(errNeedAmount);
    if(errNeedAmount == true){$(elementId).addClass('errorField');}

    return errAmount || errGVAmount || errNeedAmount;   
}
```

Actually I am going to use this function in my website multiple places please help me to make this better script.
My **[jsfiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/s3Jts/)**

Answer (score 3):

I'm not much of a jQuery freak, but I still have some points on this code. In your amountValidation function, you have some duplication and overhead:

> ```
> if(errAmount == true)
> ```

can be written:

```
if(errAmount)
```

Also you always do the same thing when an error occurs, but that's in each statement:

> ```
> if(errAmount == true){/* mark the field */};  
> if(errGVAmount == true){ /* mark the exact same field */};
> if(errNeedAmount == true { /* and yet the same thing again */ };
> ```

you can shorten this to:

```
if(errAmount || errGVAmount || errNeedAmount){ /*mark field*/ };
```

---

Your variable names could use some change too:

**errAmount** on the first look is like the geeneral error overall, not that **amount** is null / empty.
You could use **errAmountNull** instead.

**errNeedAmount** sounds like you have no amount given yet, which would be **errAmount**.
I would use **errAmountTooSmall** instead

Nobody knows, what the *GV* in **errGVAmount** stands for.
From the requirements I would call it: **errAmountUnallowedValue**